# How to aceess Blobs data in Azure blob storage using only for Azure Active directory in an organization

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage

I have a requirement that needs to access blobs only our organization people and outside people cannot access.

I have gone through lot of articles and i understand we can add a limited number of users to RBAC to access the Blob i.e., We can have up to a maximum of 2000 role assignments in each subscription but in my organization, there are around 100k people are there.

can anyone tell us the best solution which I can implement

Comment: Have you looked at groups https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-manage-groups ?

Comment: Yes buy my requirement is to add individual users instead of groups to RBAC.

Comment: @user3301440 Can you share more details on why you have the requirement to do the role assignments individually, instead of through a group?

Comment: A main important goal of our requirement is, we need to secure the blob URL ie., outside people cannot access only our organization people can access.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of granting a role assignment for each user individually, you can [create a group](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-groups-create-azure-portal), put all the users in the group, and then grant the role assignment to the group. This way you only have one role assignment which covers all the users who need access.